# Spring boot basic authentication with token for a RESTAPI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, access-token

I need to provide user login with SpringBoot application.

User login request will be a Rest request having payload comprise of "username" and "password".

I need to validate those credentials first time from DB and generate a token having validity for specific time. 
Then after login all the subsequent requests will have that token, and that token will be verified each time.

I have done the token verification part but I am really confused about first time login, I have no clue how to do it.

Even on first time login request, system is going to check for token authentication which obviously getting failed.

I want system to simply generate token on first time after validating name and password from db.

This is the first time I am implementing User login with Spring Boot Security, so I am pretty clueless about it. Although I have researched and read a lot online but still not able to figure out this part.

- **EDIT:**

Following is the security config class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
        @Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

     auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/","**/firstPage").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").
            permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll();
}
```

Following is the request that will be called after login.How to authenticate user in it using the token already generated? Token is being sent in Header of the request.

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/home")
public ResponseEntity<ConsolidateResponse> TestReques(@RequestBody TestParam testParam)
        throws Exception {

    //Some logic

   }
```

Comment: Basically, for the login endpoint, you should allow the request without auth. This can be done in your web security config class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: If you can add your web security config class (the one which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`), I can point you how you can do that.

Comment: @MadhuBhat After disabling the default auth how will application authenticate all the requests following login request? and how to handle the token expiration then?

Comment: The auth will only be disabled on the login endpoint and not on the rest of the endpoints. If you can show the code that you've tried already, I can help you.

Comment: @MadhuBhat I have updated my question. Now you will have a more clear picture.Please let me know how to authenticate subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable form login from spring security configuration class and expose one rest endpoint (/auth) you can handle login and generate token.Here i used [jwt](https://jwt.io/) for token generation.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws AuthenticationException, IOException {
        // Perform the security
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final Authentication authentication = authManager.authenticate(token);
        if (!authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Unknown username or password");
        }

        // Reload password post-security so we can generate token
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String jwtoken = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseBean);
    }
```

When use stateless authentication we can pass token parameter explicitly to controller and validate it.In case session based authentication is on we can also use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` for to retrieve current logged in user.

```
//Stateless authentication
@PostMapping(value = "/home")
public ResponseEntity<ConsolidateResponse> test(@RequestBody TestParam testParam,String token)
        throws Exception {


    Boolean isValidToken = jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(token);
    if(isValidToken) {
     //Some logic 
    }else {
     //invalid request
    }
}





@PostMapping(value = "/home")
    public ResponseEntity<ConsolidateResponse> test(@RequestBody TestBean requestToken,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User contextPrincipal, HttpServletRequest req) {

        Optional.ofNullable(contextPrincipal).orElseThrow(InvalidUserSession::new);


        //some logic
    }
```

Comment: Will this method handle authentication for subsequent requests and token expiry?

Comment: @Just_another_developer this method is for to login and token generation.For checking token is expired or this user is logged in user you can just add token parameter to "/home" endpoint and validate token.I will update my answer in a short

Comment: thank you for your assistance, I have a confusion though, if anyone has this token they can access the application even without logging in, is that true? lets say I create a token with expiry of one day and some hackers intercepts the request and get the token, now they can access the application without even really get authenticated.right?

Comment: Yes if someone has valid token then resources will be accessible for him.You can secure traffic by using https.